# How to polygonise a binary raster with python?

Tags: python, fiona, vectorization, rasterio

I already asked this in StackOverflow, but maybe it's better here. I have a ndvi raster that I binarized (I put my threshold at 0.35) with a script python and I wanted to polygonize this raster, in order to get ndvi into polygones, to store them after in a database. I found and used this code :

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.env
from rasterio.features import shapes
import fiona
mask = None
with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open('binarized_ndvi.tif') as src:
        image = src.read()

    results = (
    {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}
    for i, (s, v)
    in enumerate(
    shapes(image, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)))

    with fiona.open(
    'ndvi_shapefile.shp', 'w',
    driver='Shapefile',
    crs=src.crs,
    schema={'properties': [('raster_val', 'int')],
    'geometry': 'Polygon'}) as dst:
        dst.writerecords(results)
```

But all I get is a shapefile, with only one polygon whose shape is the same as my raster, like if only the first elment of the raster was taken into account ...

I can't send you my raster, it's too big.

Comment: What is the value of raster_val? Maybe it results from the conversion of the initial (binary) value.

Comment: raster_val is 0 if the value of the raster was <= 0.35, 1 if > 0.35

Comment: I want to mean : what is the value  of the attribute of the shapefile created?

Comment: in the shapefile, there is one attribut raster_val=0

Comment: Is this a float raster by any chance? GDAL's polygonizer is intended for thematic data, not fields of continuous values, and you'll end up with one feature for every pixel, and maybe run out of memory in the process.

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/641151

Answer (score 3):

I've used this pattern, based on [this](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/features.html) and [this](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/fb93a6425c17f25141ad308cee7263d0c491a0a9/examples/rasterio_polygonize.py). I'm not familiar with rasterio.Env - a quick look at the Docs suggests it's to access AWS. Main differences with your script are creating a mask and and having everything from `results =` statement tabbed in so it's happening with the open raster.

```
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio import features

with rasterio.open('path_to_your_raster') as src:
    image = src.read(1)
    #Make a mask
    mask = image != 1
    #iterate over shapes.
    results = (
        {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}        
        for i, (s, v) in enumerate(
            shapes = features.shapes(image, mask=mask, transform = src.transform)))

    with fiona.open(
            'ndvi_shapefile.shp', 'w',
            driver='Shapefile',
            crs=src.crs,
            schema={'properties': [('raster_val', 'int')],
            'geometry': 'Polygon'}) as dst:
        dst.writerecords(results)
```

Comment: It's not working, a file is created, but it's empty and  the script keeps running, I have to close the cmd to stop it ...

Comment: Any chance there is a way to easily flag that we do not want to coalesce neighboring like pixels and instead preserve the shape of each pixel when exporting?

Comment: Could someone clarify what the iterator "i" within the for loop of RoperMaps' script would iterate over?

Comment: [features.shapes](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.shapes) yields a list of `(polygon, value)` pairs (this are `s` and `v`). `i` comes from [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate), and is not an iterator, rather it is the count (int) of the `(s, v)` pairs returned by `features.shapes`.